# how to compress image size to byte array without affecting quality

Tags: c#, arrays, image, compression, byte

The problem is I want to send a desktop screenshot(which is Bitmap type) via UDP. As you know UDP has limited capacity to 65 000 bytes, so I have to "compress" image size to fit this capacity. I tried this:

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
Bitmap bmp = CaptureDesktopWithCursor2();
        ImageCodecInfo jpgEncoder = GetEncoder(ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder myEncoder = System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality;
        EncoderParameters myEncoderParameters = new EncoderParameters(1);
        EncoderParameter myEncoderParameter = new      EncoderParameter(myEncoder, 15L);
        myEncoderParameters.Param[0] = myEncoderParameter;
        bmp.Save(memoryStream, jpgEncoder, myEncoderParameters);
        Bitmap Bit;
                using (memoryStream)
        {

           Bit = new Bitmap(memoryStream);

            byte[] lol = imageToByteArray(Bit);
        }
```

It does change size of image, but only when you save it as .jpg file for example.

Is there anything else what I can do to fit UDP capacity(65 000)? Of course I tried resizing image(it fits cap well then) but it affects quality of this image much.

```
   public byte[] imageToByteArray(Image imageIn)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
        imageIn.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
        return ms.ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: So you're saying that the `memoryStream` contains the bytes of a JPEG-compressed image but your final `byte[] lol` does not?  That's not surprising, as you're reading the JPEG back into a `Bitmap` object.  What happens in `imageToByteArray`?

Comment: UDP is not a stream-orientated protocol like TCP. If you want to send big files over UDP, you better think of making a paket header sothat you can split the file in 64kb chunks and send them seperatly and assemble the file on the other side again, or go back to using TCP. Even if you would compress a photo file down (with a lossless compression algorithm like zipping it), if the compressed file is still larger than 64kB, you have the same problem as before.

Comment: I added imageToByteArray() code

Comment: Ok, I changed Image format in imageToByteArray -> that was the problem, size is like 5time smaller, my bad, sorry for spam.