# C# image compression for serial transmission

Tags: c#, image, serial-port, compression

This is my first question, so I hope to provide what it needs to get a decent answer.

I want to send an image received by a webcam over a serial link.
The Image is converted into a byte array and then written to the serial port.

The first issue I ran into was, that when I tried to send the image, it lead to a `TimeoutException`. Looking at the lenght of the byte array, it showed me around 1 MB of data that needs to be transmitted. Shrinking the actual size of the image resulted in an much faster transmission, but afterwards the image was way too small.

The second isuue was when I tried to compress the image. Using different methods, the size of transmission was always excactly the same.

I hope you can help me find a way to improve my implementation, so that the transmission only takes a few seconds while still maintaining reasonable resolution of the image. Thanks.

---

### Specific Information

#### Webcam Image

- The image from the webcam is received by the AForge library
- The image is handled as a Bitmap
- (Obviously) it doesn't transmit every frame, only on the click of a button

#### Serial Port

- The port uses a baud rate of 57600 bps (defined by hardware beneath)
- The `WriteTimeout`-value is set to 30s, as it would be unacceptable to wait longer than that
- Text transmission works with default values on the SerialPort-item in a WinForm

#### Image Manipulation

I used different approaches to compress the image:

Simple method like

```
public static byte[] getBytes(Bitmap img)
{
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

    byte[] output = ms.toArray();
    ms.Dispose();
    return output;
}
```

as well as more advanced methods like the one posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34362583/how-to-compress-image-size-to-byte-array-without-affecting-quality). Not only with `Encoder.Quality` but also with `Encoder.Compression`.

#### My Application

```
private void btn_Send(...)
{
    Bitmap currentFrame = getImageFromWebcam();
    
    //Bitmap sendFrame = new Bitmap(currentFrame, new Size(currentFrame.Width/10, currentFrame.Height/10));
    Bitmap sendFrame = compressImage(currentFrame);

    byte[] data = getBytes(sendFrame);

    serialPort.Write(data, 0, data.Lenght);
}
```

Comment: What size are the images and how much did you thumbnail it?  Your `getBytes` appears to be leaking, and Compression vs Quality are just inverse ways of expressing the same thing.  You cant have high Q and high Compression

Comment: The images aren't saved to disk, so I can't tell "file-size", but after the conversion the are something under 1 MB.
Do you mean by leaking, because I'm not closing the MemoryStream?

Comment: By size I meant dimensions WxH; the memstream ought be disposed. 90 vs 92 vs 95 quality actually makes a pretty big diff on size

Comment: I have to check that when I'm back on that PC. The webcam takes pictures 800x600, what happens with them "inside" AForge I don't know really. I'll add the info when I get it.

Comment: GIF encoding may not be a bad thing to try - before broadband was widespread and affordable, cams generated GIFs by default.  Indexed colors can  mean a lot less data

Comment: The size of the image is 640x480. Using GIF encoding actually reduced the size by 2/3s and finishes transmission in under 30s. But it still takes something near that.

Answer (score 0):

C Hanging the timeout property of the serial port would solve the timeout issue. How is show in this link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx. File compression works by looking at blocks of data and associating similar blocks with each other for a given segment of blocks. If your image is too unique it will not compress depending on the compression software being used.